# Remove local user password through Powershell

Tags: powershell, password, user-management

I'm trying to remove a users password through Powershell.

I know I can create a user without password like this:

```
New-LocalUser -Name "myuser" -NoPassword
```

But how do I remove a users password once it has already been set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welp nevermind, I found my answer on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53490279/set-no-password-for-a-local-user).

```
Set-LocalUser -name "myuser" -Password ([securestring]::new())
```